# How to remove this stuck cartridge

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, cartridge

Any ideas on how to get this MOEN M0036 cartridge out? I've tried to do but only have damaged edges so far. Thanks in advance.

[image]

After adjustments with file, it did not hold support as it made from copper and cover is thin

[image]

**Update**: Is it possible to use reverse drill bit and extractor to help with that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file for metal, you might try straightening those edges and using a socket. Otherwise a 12" pipe wrench is your best bet